# MVC 4, Displaying data from multiple tables & association in a view as a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Am having trouble getting data from multiple tables to display in a view, mainly because one of them is an association table.

Hi I have these 3 tables and their columns

**Theat** 
ID
Description

**Controls**
ID 
Number
Description

**ThreatHasControl**
Threat ID
Controls ID

Am trying to create a view which will display all controls associated with the selected Threat

Because am using an association table am not sure how to go about getting the data I need. I imagine I need to join the tables somehow.

I current have this method in my repository to get each Item in the ThreatHasControl table which matches the id passed for the selected threat

```
  public IQueryable<ThreatHasControl> ThreatHasControl(int ThreatID)
    {
        _context = new RiskAssessmentApplicationEntities();  
        IQueryable<ThreatHasControl> ThreatControl = _context.ThreatHasControl.Where(t => t.ThreatID == ThreatID);
        return ThreatControl;
    }
```

Am guessing it's here I need to do something else.

I also have this as my controller

```
public ActionResult GetThreatControls(int ThreatID)
        {
            repository = new EFThreatRepository();
            ViewModel MyModel = new ViewModel();
            MyModel.ThreatHasControl = repository.ThreatHasControl(ThreatID);
            List<ViewModel> ViewModelList = new List<ViewModel>();
            ViewModelList.Add(MyModel);
            return View(ViewModelList);
        }
```

Could someone offer some advice please? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to work out the solution for my question.

It turned out I just needed to enhance the linq query navigation path so that it would select and include the desired table / data

I've dropped the method from the repository for now in order to make things simpler to understand

**GetThreatControls Action Method**

```
 public ActionResult GetThreatControls(int ThreatID)
        {
            RiskAssessmentApplicationEntities _DBContext = new RiskAssessmentApplicationEntities();
            ThreatHasControl ViewModel = new ThreatHasControl();
            ViewModel.Threat = _DBContext.Threats.Single(x => x.ID == ThreatID);
            ViewModel.Controls = _DBContext
                                        .ThreatHasControl
                                        .Include("ThreatHasControl.Control")
                                        .Where(x => x.ThreatID == ThreatID)
                                        .Select(x => x.Control);

            return View(ViewModel);                                   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use ViewBag ?

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem
```

it can hold any object...

and did you set in your view :

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<ViewModel>
```

at the top of the page? and use it as a regular list?

```
foreach(var ViewModel in Model) 
{
 ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shlomi, I was using a strongly typed view with a view model as it's type which is considered better practice than using a view bag. You can find info about a view models here [View Model](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained).